# display the added product metafields in the product page

Tags: shopify

I create a one app from the admin i add the product metafields from the app and how to display the added that product metafields in the product page of the shopify frontend page

Answer (score 1):

For accessing product metafields you can use the namespace along with metafield key, like:-

```
{% assign metafields = product.metafields.namespace %}
{% assign key = 'keyname' %}
<ul>
  <li> {{ metafields[key] }}</li>
</ul>
```

For details you can refer to following :- https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield

Comment: my requirement is need to fetch the installed app product metafields only.

Comment: @Softsharavana.. You'll get `namespace` and `key` from the installed app. Replace them in the code above.

Comment: How to display below link metafields data's please check ?
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s390/sh/8c85762d-46bb-4dcf-8964-f09eccd5d24a/2952adde809bd2c5ef4bf2a3dfca7250

Comment: for each different namespace you can get it like:- `{% assign metafields = product.metafields.data %}
{% assign key = 'desc' %}
<ul>
  <li> {{ metafields[key] }}</li>
</ul>`

Comment: It display only single record of the metafield only,for example a single product can have 10metafields record with same namespace but key's are different then how to fetch that 10metafields record in the liquid page @Savina